# Change colour of div by hovering over the contents?

Tags: css, html, hover, background-color

I've found some references to changing the background colour of a different div in CSS by using:

```
#a:hover + #b{...}
```

but this doesn't work if you are trying to trigger it using a mouseover event on a link within the div layer. I can't find an answer to the problem anywhere, but it seems like it should be really easy.

I feel like I shouldn't be asking this question, but how on earth do you do it?

Comment: CSS selectors only work on child or sibling elements, not parent elements.

Answer (score 0):

If only they had enough sense to create, for us, the `:parent` pseudo class. In the meantime, you'll need to use JavaScript. Would something like this work for you?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("div#divID a#anchorID").mouseenter(function(){
        var divElement = $(this).parent();
        // Style the div to its hover style (hovering over link)
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        var divElement = $(this).parent();
        // Style the div to its base style (not hovering over link)
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Now, sticking that code in the head of the page does nothing as far as I can see.. I did put a .div:hover into the CSS file, but I didn't really think about the fact that that would just do its own thing..

Comment: That code requires jQuery, and you should replace `divID` with your div's `id` attribute and replace `anchorID` with your inner-link's `id` attribute.

Comment: I got the bit about the `id` attributes, but I didn't realise it needed jQuery. I'm still a bit new I guess, but is jQuery a separate library?

Comment: jQuery is a seprarte library that can be included on your site with just one line at the top of the `<head>` portion: `<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" /></script>`

Comment: That doesn't appear to do anything other than give the page a curiously long load time.. Is there no way to do this in CSS? I was going to try and develop this site with all the transitions, colour changes and stuff in CSS3.. Surely some of it has been standardised by now?

Comment: It can't be done purely in CSS as far as I know. There is no way of accessing parent elements in CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

If it is to only change background, you may play with pseudo-element, `position:relative/absolute` and secure layers with `z-index` :

Demo of the idea : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kCxgy